# Implement trading view terminal with vuejs

Tags: vue.js, tradingview-api

I am currently working on personal project with TradingView library to create a TradingView Terminal for my project

As right now I am working to implement **Datafeeds** for my chart

here is my TradingView.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div class="TVChartContainer" ref="chartContainer" />
</template>

<script>
import { widget } from '../../../public/charting_library/';
import datafeed from '../../lib/datafeed';

function getLanguageFromURL() {
    const regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]lang=([^&#]*)');
    const results = regex.exec(window.location.search);
    return results === null
        ? null
        : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
}

export default {
    name: 'TradingViewTerminal',
    props: {
        chartUrl: {
            required: true,
            type: String,
        },
    },
    tvWidget: null,
    mounted() {
        const container = this.$refs.chartContainer;
        const symbol = this.extractSymbolFromUrl(this.chartUrl);
        // const datafeedUrl = this.chartUrl;
        const widgetOptions = {
            symbol: symbol,
            datafeed: datafeed,
            interval: '1D',
            container: container,
            hide_side_toolbar: false,
            library_path: '/charting_library/',
            locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
            enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
            charts_storage_url: 'https://saveload.tradingview.com',
            charts_storage_api_version: '1.1',
            // fullscreen: true,
            autosize: true,
            multiple_charts_layouts: true,
            debug: true,
            details: true,
            show_popup_button: true,
            favorites: {
                intervals: ['1D', '3D', '1W', '3W', '1M'],
                chartTypes: ['Area', 'Line']
            },
            watchlist: ['NASDAQ:AAPL', 'NASDAQ:GOOGL', 'NYSE:MSFT']
            
        };

        const tvWidget = new widget(widgetOptions);
        this.tvWidget = tvWidget;

        tvWidget.onChartReady(() => {
            tvWidget.headerReady().then(() => {
                const button = tvWidget.createButton();

                button.setAttribute('title', 'Click to show a notification popup');
                button.classList.add('apply-common-tooltip');
            });
        });
    },
    methods: {
        extractSymbolFromUrl(url) {
            // First, extract the 'action' part of the query
            const actionRegex = /[?&]action=([^&#]*)/;
            const actionMatch = actionRegex.exec(url);
            if (!actionMatch) return '';  // No action parameter found

            // Decode the action parameter to get the inner URL part
            const actionValue = decodeURIComponent(actionMatch[1]);

            // Now, extract the 'symbol' from the action value
            const symbolRegex = /[?&]symbol=([^&#]*)/;
            const symbolMatch = symbolRegex.exec(action value);
            if (!symbolMatch) return '';  // No symbol parameter found in the action value

            return decodeURIComponent(symbolMatch[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        },
    },
    destroyed() {
        if (this.tvWidget !== null) {
            this.tvWidget.remove();
            this.tvWidget = null;
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

and here is my datafeeds.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { makeApiRequest } from './helpers.js';

const BASE_URL = 'https://chart.tradearies.com/chart';
const ACCESS_CODE = encodeURIComponent(localStorage.accessToken);
const USER_ID = encodeURIComponent(localStorage.session);
const USER_TOKEN = encodeURIComponent(localStorage.sessionKey);

const configurationData = {
    supported_resolutions: ['1D', '1W', '1M'],
    exchanges: [
        { value: "", name: "All Exchanges", desc: "" },
        { value: "NasdaqNM", name: "NasdaqNM", desc: "NasdaqNM" },
        { value: "NYSE", name: "NYSE", desc: "NYSE" }
    ],
    symbols_types: [
        { name: "All types", value: "" },
        { name: "Stock", value: "stock" },
        { name: "Index", value: "index" }
    ],
};

function constructApiUrl(actionPath, additionalParams = {}) {
    let baseUrl = `${BASE_URL}?access=${ACCESS_CODE}&_id=${USER_ID}&token=${USER_TOKEN}`;

    // Start constructing the action parameter
    let actionParam = `action=${actionPath}`;

    // Use '?' for the first parameter in the action path and '&' for subsequent parameters
    let isFirstParam = true;
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(additionalParams)) {
        actionParam += isFirstParam ? '?' : '&';
        isFirstParam = false;
        actionParam += `${key}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
    }

    // Append the action parameter to the base URL
    let fullUrl = `${baseUrl}&${actionParam}`;

    return fullUrl;
}



export default {
    onReady: (callback) => {
        console.log('[onReady]: Method call');
        setTimeout(() => callback(configurationData), 0);
    },

    searchSymbols: async (userInput, exchange, symbolType, onResultReadyCallback) => {
        const action = `search?query=${userInput}&type=${symbolType}&exchange=${exchange}&limit=30`;
        const url = constructApiUrl(action);
        try {
            const data = await makeApiRequest(url);
            console.log('Search Symbols:', data);
            onResultReadyCallback(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('[searchSymbols]: Error', error);
        }
    },

    resolveSymbol: async (symbolName, onSymbolResolvedCallback, onResolveErrorCallback) => {
        const action = '/history'; // Changed from '/history' to '/symbols' as it's more appropriate for symbol resolution
        const additionalParams = {
            symbol: symbolName,
            resolution: '1D',
        };
    
        const url = constructApiUrl(action, additionalParams);

        try {
            const data = await makeApiRequest(url);
            if (!data) {
                onResolveErrorCallback('Cannot resolve symbol');
                return;
            }
            const symbolInfo = {
                name: symbolName,
                ticker: symbolName,
                session: '24x7',
                timezone: 'Etc/UTC',
                minmov: 1,
                pricescale: 100,
                has_intraday: true,
                has_daily: true,
                has_weekly_and_monthly: true,
                supported_resolutions: configurationData.supported_resolutions,
                volume_precision: 2,
                data_status: 'streaming',
            };
            onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo);
            console.log('Symbol resolved:', onSymbolResolvedCallback(symbolInfo))
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('[resolveSymbol]: Error', error);
            onResolveErrorCallback('Cannot resolve symbol');
        }
    },

    getBars: async (symbolInfo, resolution, periodParams, onHistoryCallback, onErrorCallback) => {
        const { from, to } = periodParams;
    
        // Specify the action path for getting bars
        const actionPath = '/history';
    
        // Additional parameters for the action
        const additionalParams = {
            symbol: symbolInfo.name, // Use the 'name' field from symbolInfo
            resolution: resolution,
            from: from.toString(),
            to: to.toString(),
        };
    
        // Construct the URL using the modified constructApiUrl function
        const url = constructApiUrl(actionPath, additionalParams);
    
        try {
            const data = await makeApiRequest(url);
            console.log('Get Bars Data:', data);
            if (data.s !== 'ok' || data.t.length === 0) {
                // If the status is not 'ok' or there are no bars, return no data
                onHistoryCallback([], { noData: true });
                return;
            }
    
            // Map the data to the expected format for bars
            const bars = data.t.map((time, index) => ({
                time: time * 1000,
                low: parseFloat(data.l[index]),
                high: parseFloat(data.h[index]),
                open: parseFloat(data.o[index]),
                close: parseFloat(data.c[index]),
                volume: parseFloat(data.v[index]),
            }));
    
            onHistoryCallback(bars, { noData: false });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('[getBars]: Error', error);
            onErrorCallback(error);
        }
    },
    
};
```

and here is my helpers.js:

```
// Makes requests to the specified server
export async function makeApiRequest(url) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`Server request error: ${response.statusText} (${response.status})`);
        }
        return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(`Network request failed: ${error.message}`);
    }
}

// Function to generate a stock symbol string, may not be necessary if your server expects simple ticker symbols
export function generateSymbol(exchange, tickerSymbol) {
    // If you need to format symbols in a specific way for your server, modify this function accordingly
    // For simple stock ticker symbols, this function might not be necessary
    return `${exchange}:${tickerSymbol}`;
}

// Function to parse a full symbol string, may not be necessary if using simple ticker symbols
export function parseFullSymbol(fullSymbol) {
    // If your server uses a simple format for symbols (just the ticker), this function might not be necessary
    const match = fullSymbol.match(/^(.+):(.+)$/);
    if (!match) {
        return null;
    }
    return { exchange: match[1], ticker: match[2] };
}
```

so when I do console.log(data) it is giving me

> {
> s: "ok",
> t: [1386493512, 1386493572, 1386493632, 1386493692],
> c: [42.1, 43.4, 44.3, 42.8],
> o: [41.0, 42.9, 43.7, 44.5],
> h: [43.0, 44.1, 44.8, 44.5],
> l: [40.4, 42.1, 42.8, 42.3],
> v: [12000, 18500, 24000, 45000]
> }

I have try demo datafeeds with
`datafeed: new Datafeeds.UDFCompatibleDatafeed("https://demo-feed-data.tradingview.com")`

it seems working and showing the chart but when I try it with my url which is `datafeed: datafeed` it's not working

so my question is why is it not showing the chart line like datafeed using demo url

Information

1. The TradingView terminal should use this server for chart data:  
   [https://chart.tradearies.com/](https://chart.tradearies.com/%E2%80%A8)
2. The server will receive front-end calls in this format: 
   [https://chart.tradearies.com/chart?access={access_code}&_id={user_id}](https://chart.tradearies.com/chart?access=%7Baccess_code%7D&_id=%7Buser_id%7D)
   &token={user_token}&symbol={ticker_symbol}&action={UDF documented action}
3. Example: 
   https://chart.tradearies.com/chart?access=abc123&_id=abc123&token=abc123&action=/
   history?symbol=TSLA&resolution=1D&from=1704497684&to=1705361684&countback=2